# Thread safety of the reference count of a C++/CX WinRT pointer

Tags: pointers, windows-runtime, reference-counting, c++-cx

I was under the impression that the reference count to WinRT objects was thread safe, given the use case. But I've run into a bug that I don't know any other way to explain. For example, the following code crashes quite quickly:

```
ref class C sealed {
public:
    C() { }
    virtual ~C() {}
};

[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
public ref class MainPage sealed {
public:
    MainPage() : _latest(nullptr) {
        InitializeComponent();
        Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync(
            ref new Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler(
                this, 
                &MainPage::SetLatest));
        Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync(
            ref new Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler(
                this, 
                &MainPage::OnRendering));
    }
    virtual ~MainPage(){}
private:
    C^ _latest;
    void SetLatest(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction^ operation){
        while (true) {
            _latest = ref new C(); 
        }
    }
    void OnRendering(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction^ operation) {
        while (true) {
            auto c = _latest;
        }
    }
};
```

Are WinRT pointers (i.e. a ref class type like `C^`) supposed to be properly reference counted when reads/writes are racing? Is there a separate issue I'm not aware of, causing this crash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changes to the reference count of a `ref class` object are synchronized, but changes to a `T^` object are not.

You have two threads accessing `_latest` at the same time, and one of those threads is modifying `_latest`, so you need to synchronize access to `_latest`, e.g. using a `std::mutex`.

Comment: Well that explains it then. Could you link to documentation stating this?

Comment: Documenting which part?  A `ref class` is a COM class type and must therefore follow all of the COM threading rules.  A `T^` is no different from any other type that requires external synchronization.